# Path-dependent type's value not found

Tags: scala, dependent-type

Maybe I need a refresher on dependent types, but I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
trait Code { type In; type Out }

trait Handler[In, Out]

class Foo(val code: Code)(handler: Option[Handler[code.In, code.Out]])
```

Error:

```
<console>:52: error: not found: value code
       class Foo(val code: Code)(handler: Option[Handler[code.In, code.Out]])
                                                         ^
<console>:52: error: not found: value code
       class Foo(val code: Code)(handler: Option[Handler[code.In, code.Out]])
                                                                  ^
```

---

**Edit**: I can see how to work around this, now. Still I would like to know *why* the above does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logged as [issue 5712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5712) which for some reason is called an "improvement" not bug. So currently constructors cannot resolve dependent types with multiple argument lists, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround:

```
trait Foo {
  val code: Code
  val handler: Handler[code.In, code.Out] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `handler` parameter seems to have no knowledge of the `code` parameter. Would you be able to accomplish the same thing defining your traits like this?

```
trait Code[In, Out]

trait Handler[In, Out]

class Foo[In, Out](val code: Code[In, Out])(handler: Option[Handler[In, Out]])
```

Comment: As a work around, `class Foo[In0, Out0](val code: Code { type In = In0; type Out = Out0 })(handler: Option[Handler[In0, Out0]])` seems to be compiling... Still odd. I guess it's a restriction in constructors somehow.

Answer (score 1):

May be one these more simple approaches will be suitable:

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    demo1
    demo2
  }

  def demo1 {
    trait Code { type In; type Out }
    trait Handler[In, Out]
    class Foo(val code: Code) {
      private val handler: Option[Handler[code.In, code.Out]] = ???
    }
  }

  def demo2 {
    trait Code[In, Out]
    trait Handler[In, Out]
    class Foo[In, Out](val code: Code[In, Out])(handler: Option[Handler[In, Out]])
  }
}
```